# What would happen if the wind stopped blowing?

Tags: flora, wind

Assuming that the wind stopped blowing suddenly, regardless of the mechanisms involved that cause the wind to blow, how would it affect the world, with a specific focus on nature? I can imagine that plants and trees would have a much harder time pollinating, for example.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please give a good read at our [help]. Question along the line of "What if X happened?" are not a good fit for us, and yours falls in that bucket. Try better scoping your question.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll take a look at the help center and try to narrow my scope.

Comment: Thanks for working to edit your question! While you work on it, I've "voted to close" the question. I don't think it's a bad question, it's just an attempt to prevent smart alecks like me from writing an answer like ***well, there goes this year's kite festival** and similarly silly & unhelpful answers. Once you get your query in shape, I'll happy either rescind the VTC or else vote to reopen!

Comment: I'm following elemtilas for very similar reasons, I've seen questions that became quite good get buried in drivel at this stage of the game, and with the same assurance that I'll be happy to reopen it and contribute an answer when you've done some work on it.

Comment: (My smart-aleck answer, for posterity: "The earth would quickly turn into Venus, for lack of convective cooling". But tbh I'm not even sure how true that would be. Good luck working on your question, ntailedfox!)

Comment: Rain would *only* rain on the ocean, where it evaporated from. Inland would become utterly dry, hot, barren deserts. The sort of thing where one expects just blowing sandstorms, if someone had not stolen the wind for that.

Comment: @PcMan Not that this is important, but couldn't water vapor still get around the atmosphere via diffusion? If we take "no wind" to mean that the average of the horizontal component of molecules' movement is zero, we could still have gradual dispersal of individual water molecules into drier air around it.

Comment: @Qami Yes it would! At a rate of between 1/1000 and 1/5000th as much. i.e. utterly negligible.

Comment: @Qami actually ran the calc. over continental distance, the rate of water vapor spread by diffusion only will be less than 1e-7 of normal rainfall rates. Movement due to a gradient is *abysmally* slow when the gradient stretches over thousands of km.

Comment: Not enough to maintain any useful amount of rain, certainly.